# How to avoid accessing table at same time as another instance?

Tags: python, sql-server, pandas, sqlalchemy, azure-sql-database

I have a Log table that I send data to when an event happens. Sometimes there are multiple events that happen at basically the same time. Sometimes this causes duplicates in a value that I'm grabbing and incrementing before sending it back to the table with some other data.
Problem arises when two instances are doing this, at near the same time. I've tried solutions to try and make sure only one instance is run but I've had no luck. So what else can I do?

If I started a transaction like so:

```
with conn.begin() as transaction:
    #do what I need
    transaction.commit()
```

Will this lock the other instance out until this transaction is done? If it does, then we're almost there, but I foresee some error handling of some sort so that the instance that gets locked out re runs its process again.

Using python, pandas, SQLAlchemy and I'm interacting with an Azure SQL db/SQL Server db

Comment: *"Sometimes this causes duplicates in a value that I'm grabbing and incrementing before sending it back to the table with some other data"* Sounds like you should be using an `IDENTITY`/`SEQUENCE`

Comment: I hope you don't use select max(someid) + 1 from bigTable to do what you're doing

Comment: @siggemannen Essentially, yes. I'm here to learn though.

Comment: Why are you doing that? SQL Server has tools for generating an always increasing value.

Comment: @ThomA Some duplicates are fine. One "Batch" consists of an xml and csv file. I also like to record when the files were started and when they were completed.

Comment: Switch to an `IDENTITY` or `SEQUENCE` and you can't get duplicates. Which you want depends on your requirements, and we don't have enough information to know which you want/need.

Comment: if you want to have same id for multiple rows, SEQUENCE is your ticket. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-sequence-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16